# WSL after trying all the steps to upgrade to version 2 if get a failure: WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Launch any WSL from within VS Code "No WSL distros found. New distros can be installed from the Microsoft Store.

Source Remote - WSL (Extensions)

BUTON: "Add Distro" --> takes you to the store. Install the version of Linux, and try to start it and you get the following. I've had WSL working before and now cannot get it back to the original working WSL.

I tried some things to update to version 2 and I could list version with command "`WSL -l -v`" it showed up but not anymore. I've got the features set properly. WSL feature is enabled. I did try setting a bios "Virtualization Technology" this is on a HP laptop with AMD 64 bit cpu. That is off now after finding it doesn't help.

Features on: "Virtual Machine Platform", "Windows Hypervisor Platform" "Windows Subsystem for Linux" There are others but these seem relevant.

Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Error: 0x80370102 The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.

Press any key to continue...

Answer (score 1):

This had to have the bios setting. Also because of being Windows 10 Home didn't have Hyper V feature, but there is a batch that can add this. There is a msi to install WSL 2 so wsl.exe was upgraded. This got the results to show WSL version 2 for ubuntu-20-04 install Also there was some resets needed to get the  "WSL -l -v" command to have running.

I don't know 100% certain that these are the cure to the issue. But may help someone who cannot get the Linux to start w/out various error running on windows subsystem Linux. Took me better part of a day to fix.

find the following by googling "del hyper-v.txt" you will hit a page telling you "How to activate Hyper-V in Windows 10 Home"

source of batch command
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/915

```
pushd "%~dp0"
dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\*Hyper-V*.mum >hyper-v.txt
for /f %%i in ('findstr /i . hyper-v.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i"
del hyper-v.txt
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V -All /LimitAccess /ALL
pause
```

Reboot, still not running, but needed the following sequence.

```
wsl --shutdown
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
```

```
wsl -l -v
```

```
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Running         2
```

initially there was a root user only. Updated new user with the following in %userprofile% folder. Omit the dash and dot.

Ubuntu2004 config --default-user addedUsername

The WSL now is seen by VS Code extensions and no longer flagging to update to version 2. Now on to RxJS tutorial under VS Code.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure all related settings in the bios are enabled.
2. Make sure all related features in the windows features are turned on.

Alright, if there is an error:

1. Turn off all related features
2. Restart it.
3. Turn on.
4. Restart it.

related features = ( virtualization )